# How to automatically deploy a webapp?

Tags: html, web-applications, google-apps-script

In creating an application in **Google Apps Script**, I found a problem, which I haven't solved yet. I hope you can help me with this.

I would like to automatically deploy a webapp, after I created a page (in Google Apps Script), in Google Sites. I expected it would be possible with

```
page.setHtmlContent("html code of the webapp");
```

However, I found that it only deploys an image, instead. Moreover, I saw that specific parts of the `htmlContent` are left out, namely:

```
data-origsrc="url"
```

and

```
data-type="maestro"
```

and

```
data-props="align:center;borderTitle:Apps Script Gadget;height:500;showBorder:false;showBorderTitle:false;width:800;wrap:false;"
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Or maybe how to automatically deploy a webapp in a different way?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't think we can [manage versions](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1703) or [edit gadgets](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=572) automatically yet.

Answer (score 0):

1) you cant auto publish an app. It would have security issues so I doubt it will ever be available.
2) thats not how you embed an apps script on a site. You need to publish it and insert it as a gadget.

Comment: Dear Zig Mandel,
Indeed, that isn't the formal way add an app to a page. But I found that if you take the html-code of the script (by: edit page --> html), and copy it to another page, the app will work on the other page. So, in tried to be creative and saved these html-codes in a database so that my script could automatically deploy scripts in a page. However, that isn't possible, apparently.

At least, thank you for your reply.